# PHP - Search Brands by Category ID and ORDERED BY CATEGORY NOT EQUAL

Tags: php

I'm creating a submenu called BRAND.
So, I've got a table with Categories ID and brand NAMES.

---

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQwoZ.png -> Print from DB and MENU

---

What i'm trying to do is...
The code need to show only the BRANDs from $_GET.

Example, is GET is 42, only shows "Fatos" and "Camisolas".

But my code is wrong in something, its showing all... help

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT ads_brand FROM public_ads WHERE category_id != ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['ads']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($ads_brand);       
$stmt->store_result();

if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<div class='page-header text-center wsub'><p>Categorias <i class='fas fa-angle-right'></i> <b>". $_GET['article'] ."</b></p></div>";
    echo '<div class="dropdown"><button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Por Marca<span class="caret"></span></button> <ul class="dropdown-menu">';

    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo '<li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> '. $ads_brand .'</a></li>'; 
    }

    echo "</ul></div><hr/>";                
}
```

Comment: Change `s` in `bind_param` to `d`, you are passing number, not string.

Comment: of course, but do u have a solution for this?... because.. is showing all..

Comment: Maybe i'm blind... the error could be in my eyes xDD

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to select **only** rows that have `category_id` same as `$_GET['ads']`?

What are you doing right now is selecting **everything** with `category_id` **different** than `$_GET['ads']`.

From

`"SELECT ads_brand FROM public_ads WHERE category_id != ?"`

To

`"SELECT ads_brand FROM public_ads WHERE category_id = ?"`

Comment: I fix it... but is showing me multiple equal brands, example "Iphone, Iphone, Iphone" i only want to shoe 1 time.. how can i do it? @Oen44

Comment: Well, that's maybe because you have same brand in multiple rows?